# typeahead/bloodhound with multiple remote datasources

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

I want to use twitter's typeahead to realize a search autosuggest. This autosuggest should provide term suggestions (terms) and product suggestions (products). Both suggestions can be retrieved remotely. However, it seems that the typeahead method is only calling one remote URL. The second one is never called.

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var termEngine = new Bloodhound({
    name: 'searchTerms',
    remote: "/index.php?terms=true&g=%QUERY",
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    cache: false
  });
  var productEngine = new Bloodhound({
    name: 'products',
    remote: "/index.php?products=true&g=%QUERY",
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    cache: false
  });

  termEngine.initialize();
  productEngine.initialize();

  $('#searchField').typeahead(
      {
        name: 'searchTerms',
        source: termEngine.ttAdapter()
      }, {
        name: 'products',
        source: productEngine.ttAdapter()
  });
}
```

I have also added a jsfiddle link with the same issue (although a different remote data source): http://jsfiddle.net/r4cnares/1/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved: I have to add an empty option object to the typeahead method:

```
$('#searchField').typeahead({},
  {
    name: 'searchTerms',
    source: termEngine.ttAdapter()
  }, {
    name: 'products',
    source: productEngine.ttAdapter()
});
```

This ensures both requests are executed.